# IBM Watson Visual Rec API for PHP

Tags: php, ibm-watson

Is it possible to use the [Watson API](https://developer.ibm.com/watson/) in a PHP Project?.

I'm Total a newbie, if anyone has experience or some sample code here I would be very thankful.

Comment: i've searched in google and github but most of them for node.js

Comment: The API is RESTful. So you can use network tools such as cURL(http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php)

Answer (score 1):

@Ruslam-Osmanov is right, you can use cURL to call most REST APIs. Here is an example of using that method with the [Personality Insights](http://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/personality-insights.html) services: https://developer.ibm.com/answers/questions/200245/how-to-use-php-curl-to-call-rest-api-personality-i.html

I am a developer evangelist with IBM Watson Developer Cloud.

Comment: Out of Topic. i found node js template and successed to run on localhost, but the Vis-Rec API not working(detail "Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials"). do you have experience to use watson without bluemix and how? Thanks

Comment: You have to use Bluemix to provision credentials, but can run applications anywhere with Internet access. See this post for more and links to hiding credentials from end users: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35952057/can-i-use-ibm-watson-services-without-bluemix/35952987#35952987

Comment: @RichEdwards Please include all relevant details in the answer; link-only answers are not useful to this website.

Comment: [This project](https://github.com/darrynten/watson-personality-insights-php) is specifically for PHP and Watson Personality interactions!